python Pandas convert a column of two dimension list to a new dataframe
how do I convert this dataframe which includes a column of two dimension list to a new dataframe.
                                           values                   name
[[1717813770, 1044], [1717813800, 1045], [1717...                rx_busy
[[1717813770, 8648172], [1717813800, 8648178],...               rx_reuse
[[1717813770, 2705571], [1717813800, 2725355],...               rx_bytes
[[1717813770, 4173437], [1717813800, 4523487],...               tx_bytes

In column value, each item comprise of [epoch timestamp, value] x 10. I want to convert it to a new DF, in which the head is from column 'name' above, it would be something like this,
rx_busy rx_reuse rx_bytes tx_bytes   timestamp
1044    8648172  2705571  4173437   1717813770
1045    8648178  2725355  4523487   1717813800
......

I can't think of any way to do it. many thanks for help.

Thanks all for helping. I was assuming I will get 10 samples, 30 seconds apart every 5 minutes. but, I just found out I could missing one or two samples. Is there a way to add a check to add NaN in case missing data

I've updated my answer to address your comment. If this isn't what you're looking for, you can edit your question and update it with a minimal reproducible example including data that reproduces the problem with missing samples, and an expected outcome.

One possible vectorized approach:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "values": [
            [[1717813770, 1044], [1717813800, 1045], [1717813860, 1046]],
            [[1717813770, 8648172], [1717813800, 8648178], [1717813860, 8648184]],
            [[1717813770, 2705571], [1717813800, 2725355], [1717813860, 2745210]],
            [[1717813770, 4173437], [1717813800, 4523487], [1717813860, 4854279]],
        ],
        "name": ["rx_busy", "rx_reuse", "rx_bytes", "tx_bytes"],
    }
)

df = df.explode("values")
df[['timestamp', 'values']] = df['values'].tolist()
df = df.pivot(index="timestamp", columns="name", values="values").reset_index()

name   timestamp  rx_busy  rx_bytes  rx_reuse  tx_bytes
0     1717813770     1044   2705571   8648172   4173437
1     1717813800     1045   2725355   8648178   4523487
2     1717813860     1046   2745210   8648184   4854279


Edit: If I understand your additional requirement correctly, if you want to add NaN for missing data, you can create a full range of timestamps at 30-second intervals, then merge df into it:
full_range = pd.Series(
    np.arange(df["timestamp"].min(), df["timestamp"].max() + 1, 30), name="timestamp"
)
df = pd.merge(full_range, df, on="timestamp", how="left")

    timestamp  rx_busy   rx_bytes   rx_reuse   tx_bytes
0  1717813770   1044.0  2705571.0  8648172.0  4173437.0
1  1717813800   1045.0  2725355.0  8648178.0  4523487.0
2  1717813830      NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
3  1717813860   1046.0  2745210.0  8648184.0  4854279.0

